# Counting a value within a specific range in array in SAS

Tags: arrays, count, sas, sum

So my dataset looks like this:

```
ABC1 ABC2 ABC3 ABC4 ABC5 DEF1 DEF2 DEF3 DEF4 DEF5  
  1    0    0    1    .    0    1    1    0   .
```

I want my output to be:

```
XYZ1 XYZ2 XYZ3 XYZ4 XYZ5
 0    1    1    0    .
```

Basically if DEF2 = 1 and count of ABC3 and ABC4 and ABC5 of 1 is > 0 then XYZ2 is 1.

I have tried the following code but it doesnt work

```
data want;
set have;
array ABC ABC:;
array DEF DEF:;
array XYZ [5] $1;
do i = 1 to dim(ABC)-5;

if ABC(i) = . then XYZ(i) = '';
else if (DEF(i) = 1 and sum(ABC(i+1), ABC(i+3)) > 0) then XYZ(i) = 1;
else XYZ(i) = 0;
end;
drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Are the XYZ variables numbers or character strings? You are treating them differently in different parts of your code.  Do you want to check three values of ABC or just the two that your code is trying to check?  Your DO loop will not run for your example since you are iterating from 1 to zero.

Comment: Regarding 'count of' do you mean the variables `ABC1` to `ABC5` contain a frequency value ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets pivot things for a better understanding

```
index ABC DEF XYZ (wanted)
----- --- --- ---
  1    1   0   0 (because DEF=0)
  2    0   1   1 (sum ABC index 2..5 because DEF=1 @ index 2)
  3    0   1   1 (sum ABC index 3..5 because DEF=1 @ index 3)
  4    1   0   0 (because DEF=0)
  5    .   .   . (because DEF=.)
```

Now apply that understanding to processing variables of the row when arrayed.  The items will be processed from 5 to 1, so a running_sum can be computed and applied when necessary.

```
data want;
  set have;

  array abc abc:;
  array def def:;
  array xyz(5);

  running_sum = .;
  do index = dim(abc) to 1 by -1;
    if not missing(abc(index)) then running_sum + abc(index);
    if def(index) in (., 0)
      then xyz(index) = def(index);
      else xyz(index) = running_sum;
  end;
run;
```

Not all processing rules are stated in the question, such as

- the case `abc(j) = .` and `abc(k) ne .` and `k > j`

Such a case may never happen.